# Изменять свойство блока при изменении его размера

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Всем доброго времени суток!
Помогите решить задачку, как сделать чтобы  общий фон блока был разделенным по 50px на разноцветные света и при изменении размера блока добавлять или уменьшать количество цветов и при наведении на определенный блок света показывал который в списке этот свет.
Заранее спасибо за ответ:)

Comment: Вы имеете в виду не хочет ли кто нибудь решить вашу задачку за вас? Конкретнее, что у вас не получается сделать?

Comment: Думаете если продублировать вопрос, то люди будут охотнее Вам помогать? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/833666/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%BD-%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC-%D0%BF%D0%BE-50px-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8

Comment: Я сейчас делаю фамильное дерево

Comment: Я сейчас делаю фамильное дерево  и мне нужно разделить весь блок по годом чтобы пользователь смог увидеть сразу кто в каком периоде времени родился  я попытался сделать для каждого поколение свой свет но это не коректно потомучто старшый брат может быть старше на 30 лет а мне нужно разделить по 10 годам и я бы хотел узнать как разделить оющий фон блока

Answer (score 0):

1. Свет и цвет - разные понятия.
2. Сделайте блоку градиент в качестве background-image. Например, такой:

`background-image:linear-gradient(to right, red 50px, orange 50px, orange 100px, yellow 100px, yellow 150px, green 150px, green 200px, lightblue 200px, lightblue 250px, blue 250px, blue 300px, purple 300px);`

3. С наведением сложнее. Вариант - в "общий блок" сложить пачку блоков с разными `background-color` и при наведении мышки на один из них скриптом брать значение фонового цвета у этого блока.